# How to fix "Invariant Violation:Text string must be rendered within a <text> component"?

Tags: react-native

I done everything i searched in internet but still it's causing some trouble

Code from Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<View><text>hihihi</text></View>);
    }
}
```

Code from app.js

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./app/views/Home.js"
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<Home />);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<View><text>hihihi</text></View>);
    }
}
```

to

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<View><Text>hihihi</Text></View>);
    }
}
```

it's `</Text>` not `</text>` T is capital